# Получение объекта DateTime:: из strtotime

Tags: php, дата, datetime

Доброго времени суток. Имеется метка времени Unix `$dt`

```
var_dump($dt); //int(1497420000)
```

Как преобразовать её в объект DateTime:: без дополнительного преобразования (смотри ниже)?

```
$dt = '1497420000';
$dt_format = 'd-m-Y H:i:s';
$dt_new = date($dt_format, $dt);
$date_obj = DateTime::createFromFormat($dt_format, $dt_new);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможные форматы смотрим [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.createfromformat.php)

```
 $timestamp = 1423522800;  // Timestamp for 2015-02-10
 $date1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $timestamp);
```